# How to create variables by substracting elements from group? e.g., value of each row of each group - first row of group value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the following example, what would be the best to group so that there could be a new column that is formed by taking first year in each group and subtracting by current year. For example in in row with index 0 it would be NaN, row with index 1 , it would = 1, row with index 2 it would = 3, row with index 4 = 1 and so forth.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '4', '4'],
...                    'Year': [2000, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2002, 2001, 2003]})
>>> print(df)
  id  Year
0  1  2000
1  1  2001
2  1  2003
3  2  2004
4  2  2005
5  3  2002
6  4  2001
7  4  2003
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform `Year` with `first` to get the first year per `id`, then subtract this from `Year` column to get difference, finally `mask` the values where difference is `0`:

```
s = df['Year'] - df.groupby('id')['Year'].transform('first')
df['col'] = s.mask(s == 0)
```

---

```
  id  Year  col
0  1  2000  NaN
1  1  2001  1.0
2  1  2003  3.0
3  2  2004  NaN
4  2  2005  1.0
5  3  2002  NaN
6  4  2001  NaN
7  4  2003  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer from @Shubham is shorter than my answer, I want to put here another approach:

#### 1. Looking for the firsts of each group

You need to know what are each first value of each group, for that reason, you are going to use [`Groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html?highlight=first#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first) method:

```
firsts = df.groupby('id').first()
print(first)
```

The `first` variable is a dataframe with this structure:

```
    Year
id  
1   2000
2   2004
3   2002
4   2001
```

#### 2. Looking at how many values have each group

For this, you will use [`Groupby.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html?highlight=count#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count) method

```
howmany = df.groupby('id').count().rename(columns={'Year': 'Howmany'})
print(howmany)
```

The `howmany` variable is a dataframe with this structure:

```
    Howmany
id  
1     3
2     2
3     1
4     2
```

#### 3. Create an information dataframe

Information will be an auxiliary dataframe with information about what is the first `Year` of each group and how many values has that group. You need to use a simple [`Dataframe.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html?highlight=join#pandas.DataFrame.join) method

```
information = firsts.join(howmany).reset_index()
print(information)
```

The `information` variable is a dataframe with this structure:

```
   id   Year    Howmany
0   1   2000      3
1   2   2004      2
2   3   2002      1
3   4   2001      2
```

#### 4. Create a column with each first value of each group

You are going to create a new column called `col` which has the first `Year` of each group repeated according to the number of values.

```
lists_df = []
for value in information.itertuples():
    lists_df.append(pd.DataFrame(data=[value.Year]*value.Howmany))

df['col'] = pd.concat(lists_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

So far, our `df` looks like this:

```
    id  Year     col
0   1   2000    2000 <--- First value of group 1, it is repeated 3 times because group 1 has 3 values
1   1   2001    2000
2   1   2003    2000
3   2   2004    2004 <--- First value of group 2, it is repeated 2 times because group 2 has 2 values
4   2   2005    2004
5   3   2002    2002
6   4   2001    2001
7   4   2003    2001
```

You can realize that `col` column has exactly the first value of each group

#### 5. Use [`Groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html?highlight=shift#pandas.DataFrame.shift) to shift `col` column by each group

So, if you do

```
df.groupby('id')['col'].shift()
```

Then, you will get:

```
        col
0       NaN
1    2000.0
2    2000.0
3       NaN
4    2004.0
5       NaN
6       NaN
7    2001.0
```

Finally, a simple vectorized substraction is enough, between `Year` and `col` column:

```
df['col'] = df['Year'] - df.groupby('id')['col'].shift()
```

#### All code together!

```
firsts = df.groupby('id').first()
howmany = df.groupby('id').count().rename(columns={'Year': 'Howmany'})
information = firsts.join(howmany).reset_index()
lists_df = []
for value in information.itertuples():
    lists_df.append(pd.DataFrame(data=[value.Year]*value.Howmany))
df['col'] = pd.concat(lists_df).reset_index(drop=True)
df['col'] = df['Year'] - df.groupby('id')['col'].shift()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id   Year    col
0   1   2000    NaN
1   1   2001    1.0
2   1   2003    3.0
3   2   2004    NaN
4   2   2005    1.0
5   3   2002    NaN
6   4   2001    NaN
7   4   2003    2.0
```